# If a call to contract B depends on some state in contract A, can I send both transactions in the same block?

Tags: nft, evm, wagmi

Here's the general interaction: I have a dApp that allows a user to mint a VolcanoNFT in two ways: either by sending 0.001 ETH, or by "sending" an ERC-20 token called LAVACOIN.

For payment with ETH, it's really simple because everything is done in a single transaction, calling the `mint` function with `{value: 0.001 ether}`.

For payment with LAVACOIN, here's the flow:

1. User approves the NFT contract address to spend 1 LAVACOIN
2. User calls the `mint` function with 0 ether

If I send both the approve and mint transaction one after the other in the same block, without waiting for a confirmation on the approve transaction, will the VolcanoNFT contract "see" the approval? Or do I indeed have to wait for a confirmation before sending the `mint` call?

Here's the source code for the VolcanoNFT, linked at the relevant line: https://github.com/ziad-saab/hardhat-starter/blob/master/packages/blockchain/contracts/VolcanoNFT.sol#L37

And here's how my dApp is currently handling the interaction: https://github.com/ziad-saab/hardhat-starter/blob/master/packages/webapp/src/Mint.tsx#L103

In addition to an answer to my "order of operations" question, feel free to give feedback on the logic used in `Mint.tsx`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't know for a fact that your first transaction (i.e. the approve) will be included in the same block than the second transaction (i.e. the mint), and you won't know which transaction is included in the block before the other (i.e. 'higher' in the block).

So no, I don't think you should rely on a 'same block' approach